# ASP.net Custom Multiple control validator javascript issue

Tags: .net, javascript, asp.net, validation, user-controls

I've used the code in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultiDependValidator.aspx) before to create a custom validator to validate mupltiple controls on a page. Using the "inline method" to hook up the validators just beofre the closing form tag.

This time I'm making a user control and want the control to handle the generatio/rendering of the javascript to hook up the validators. The problem is that using the RegisterStartupScript method to add the script will add the script **before** the automatically added ValidatorOnSubmit() method.

My current thought for a work around is to have a method that can be called from the page containg the control to add the javascritp to hook up the validators but I'd rather have a control I can just drop onto a page without the user having to worry about hooking anything else up.

Is there a way, from my user control to render the javascript to hook up the validaors **after** the ValidatorOnSubmit() method?

I've tried this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript and  this.Page.RegisterStartupScript with both rendering the javascript too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up use [this control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultipleFieldsValidator.aspx). I really whish I'd found this earlier in the day!